# Import api url data more than 10 000 rows with Python

Tags: python, json, api

i try to import an json url (api), the file have "nhits":20843

So this is my url : https://opendata.reseaux-energies.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=injections-regionales-quotidiennes-consolidees-rpt&q=&rows=20843&facet=date&facet=region&facet=filiere&facet=plage_de_puissance

This is my code :

```
import requests
site = "https://opendata.reseaux-energies.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=injections-regionales-quotidiennes-consolidees-rpt&q=&rows=20843&facet=date&facet=region&facet=filiere&facet=plage_de_puissance"
r = requests.get(site)
data = r.json()
```

And i have a error message :

```
'raw_params': {'expected': '-1 <= rows <= 10000', 'field_value': 20843, 'field_name': 'rows'}, 'raw_message': 'Invalid field in API request: {field_name} with value {field_value}. Expected: {expected}', 'error_key': 'InvalidFieldInAPIRequestExpectedException'}
```

How can I avoid the error

ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: It looks like you can only request up to 10000 rows at a time.  So you'll have to request the first 10000, then the next 10000, then the final 843.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting to many resuklts at once. The error says that you may only request 10K reusults at once. So you need to split your request into multiple parts if you want to get every single result.

For my code i reduced the results per request to 1000 so that the request does not time out. Then for each subsequent request I increment the start-parameter of you api by adding `start=" + str(i) + "&` to the url. See Documentation https://help.opendatasoft.com/apis/ods-search-v1/#available-apis

```
import requests
import math
datas = []
for i in range(math.ceil(20843/1000)):
    site = "https://opendata.reseaux-energies.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=injections-regionales-quotidiennes-consolidees-rpt&q=&rows=1000&start="+str(i*1000)+"&facet=date&facet=region&facet=filiere&facet=plage_de_puissance"
    r = requests.get(site)
    datas.append(r.json())
```

Comment: Just fixed a bug about a missing `&` thanks to @JohnGordon. I have verified that it works now.